# ASP.NET Health Monitoring

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have an `ASP.NET 4.0`  Web form application.

We do have Session drop issues.

To investigate the reason, I want to enable built-in "`HealMonitoring`" feature 
to track the App domain issues.

The problem is I only see this feature is documented under ASP.NET 2.0.

Do you know if this still works for ASP.Net 4.0? are there any up to date documents?

I'm looking for code to add to the **master** Web.conig to enable this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's Visual Studio 2010 which I think should be 4.0: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398933(v=vs.100).aspx.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes